# XPath to find ancestor node containing CSS class

Tags: java, xpath, selenium

I am writing some Selenium tests and I need to be able to find an ancestor of a `WebElement` that I have already found.

This is what I'm trying but is returning no results

```
// checkbox is also a WebElement
WebElement container = checkbox.findElement(By.xpath(
    "current()/ancestor-or-self::div[contains(@class, 'x-grid-view')]") );
```

The image below shows the div that I have selected highlighted in dark blue and the one I want to find with an arrow pointing at it.

[image]

**UPDATE**
Tried prestomanifesto's suggestion and got the following error

```
[cucumber]       org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector ./ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'x-grid-view']) is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
[cucumber]       [InvalidSelectorError] Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression ./ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'x-grid-view']) because of the following error:
[cucumber]       [Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "51" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR)"  location: "file:///C:/Users/JUAN~1.MEN/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous849245187842385828webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriv
```

**Update 2**
Really weird, even by ID is not working

```
[cucumber]       org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:{"method":"xpath","selector":"./ancestor::div[@id='gridview-1252']"}
```

**Update 3**

The following XPATH works, but is brittle

```
../../../../../../../*
```

Comment: Did you try "./" instead of "current()/"?

Comment: @prestomanifesto I just did, still not getting any results...  Added the error message

Comment: The expression is perfectly legal. For debugging purposes, try `ancestor::div[1]`, `ancestor::div[@id='gridview-1252'][1]` and so on, this will help locating the point where it breaks.

Comment: @Tomalak: It must be something with selenium's xpaths. I tried your suggestions and there was still no element found, except for what I showed in my **Update 3**

Comment: Looking into my crystal ball tells me that you you have XHTML here. Is that true?

Comment: @Tomalak What do you mean "I have XHTML" here? The HTML is generated by Ext-JS. I'm not sure that their HTML is 100% XHTML compatible

Comment: Does the document have an XHTML doctype? Because if it does, you need to use a namespace in your XPath. The point that even the simplest expressions do not select any nodes at all leaves little room for any other interpretation.

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm using 
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Comment: Okay, then I give up. If something as simple as `./ancestor::div` does not produce any result, the problem definitley is *not* with the XPath. It must be somewhere else. But for kicks, could you please try if `./ancestor::*[local-name()='div' and contains(@class, 'x-grid-view')]` works?

Comment: @downvoter Please help improve the question with a comment

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This *should* select the element you want

```
./ancestor::div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' x-grid-view ')][1]
```

In plain English: Of all the ancestor `div` elements that have `' x-grid-view '` in their class, select the first (closest) one.

Notes:

- I concat spaces as a defensive measure to prevent partial matches.
- `current()` is an XSLT function, not an XPath one. It has no meaning outside of XSLT. The current node is expressed as `.` in XPath.

Comment: An upvote for the effort: my guess is that my version of selenium doesn't support `/ancestor::`

Comment: @Juan: This would be *most* unusual. Did you find *any* XPath that returns a node (apart from those of the `../../*` variety)?

Comment: I haven't tried your latest suggestion `./ancestor::*[local-name()='div' and contains(@class, 'x-grid-view')]`, will try it as soon as my environment is ready to run tests again, I broke a few things... thanks again

Comment: If that happens to work, you are facing a namespace issue. If it doesn't work, you'll have to do some debugging as to what `.findElement(By.xpath(...` actually supports. It doesn't make any sense *at all* that `ancestor::` won't work.

Comment: I will do some deeper debugging with a very simple HTML page and no other code surrounding it. Will post results here

Comment: I'm curious. There has to be some simple reason behind this odd behavior.

Comment: Crazy `ancestor::*[local-name()='div' and contains(@class, 'x-grid-view')]` seems to do the trick. It's weird since I don't need that qualification in any of my other queries

Comment: @Juan Then this looks a lot like an XML namespace issue. Your document seems to be in XHTML mode for some reason. That's the direction you should be digging.

Comment: It's weird that the following xpath works if I use the `$x()` function in chrome and Firefox `$x("id('gridview-1274')//span[contains(text(), 'cdk2')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'x-grid-view')]")`

Comment: @Juan Nice, I did not even know about the `$x()` function until now. As I said, the XPath itself is fine. Does `//body` select anything in selenium?

Comment: Yes, the problem only happens when using `/ancestor::` or `/ancestor-or-self`

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak, your solution worked for my scenario the first time.  That's handy.