# How to scrape data from this specific webpage and save the output in a data frame?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am new to webscraping with `R` and I need help to get through this task. I am trying to scrape data from this specific webpage and I am stuck at a particular point in the whole process.

Here is the URL: [webpage](https://www.hotelissima.fr/s/h/ile-maurice/mahebourg/astroea-beach.html?searchType=accomodation&searchId=4&guideId=&filters=&withFlights=false&airportCode=PAR&airport=Paris&search=astroea%20beach&startdate=08%2F11%2F2021&stopdate=15%2F11%2F2021&duration=7&travelers=En%20couple&travelType=&rooms%5B0%5D.nbAdults=2&rooms%5B0%5D.nbChilds=0&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B0%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B1%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B2%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B3%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B4%5D=)

Basically, I am trying to capture 3 elements from the webpage:

(1) Room Type (css selector: `.room h3`)

(2) Meal Plan (css selector: `.meal-plan-title`)

(3) Price (css selector: `.price`)

I have been able to extract those values from the webpage. However I am having a hard time matching the values as displayed on the webpage.

Here are how my `R` codes stand:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tables)

MealPlan <- read_html("https://www.hotelissima.fr/s/h/ile-maurice/mahebourg/astroea-beach.html?searchType=accomodation&searchId=4&guideId=&filters=&withFlights=false&airportCode=PAR&airport=Paris&search=astroea+beach&startdate=08%2F11%2F2021&stopdate=15%2F11%2F2021&duration=7&travelers=En+couple&travelType=&rooms%5B0%5D.nbAdults=2&rooms%5B0%5D.nbChilds=0&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B0%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B1%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B2%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B3%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B4%5D=") %>%
#html_nodes(".meal-plan-text") %>%
html_nodes(".meal-plan-title") %>%
html_text()

MealPlan

Price <- read_html("https://www.hotelissima.fr/s/h/ile-maurice/mahebourg/astroea-beach.html?searchType=accomodation&searchId=4&guideId=&filters=&withFlights=false&airportCode=PAR&airport=Paris&search=astroea+beach&startdate=08%2F11%2F2021&stopdate=15%2F11%2F2021&duration=7&travelers=En+couple&travelType=&rooms%5B0%5D.nbAdults=2&rooms%5B0%5D.nbChilds=0&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B0%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B1%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B2%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B3%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B4%5D=") %>%
  html_nodes(".price") %>%
  html_text()

Price


RoomType <- read_html("https://www.hotelissima.fr/s/h/ile-maurice/mahebourg/astroea-beach.html?searchType=accomodation&searchId=4&guideId=&filters=&withFlights=false&airportCode=PAR&airport=Paris&search=astroea+beach&startdate=08%2F11%2F2021&stopdate=15%2F11%2F2021&duration=7&travelers=En+couple&travelType=&rooms%5B0%5D.nbAdults=2&rooms%5B0%5D.nbChilds=0&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B0%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B1%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B2%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B3%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B4%5D=") %>%
  html_nodes(".room h3") %>%
  html_text()

RoomType
```

I would like to have the output in a data frame as follows:

```
   RoomType               MealPlan         Price

Chambre Standard     Petit Dej.+Diner    584 € / pers
Chambre Standard     All inclusive       864 € / pers
Chambre Confort      Petit Dej.+Diner    715 € / pers
Chambre Confort      All inclusive       995 € / pers
Bungalow             Petit Dej.+Diner    781 € / pers
Bungalow             All inclusive       1061 € / pers
Chambre Deluxe       Petit Dej.+Diner    847 € / pers
Chambre Deluxe       All inclusive       1127 € / pers
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slower approach to the answer. I've added the attribute `trim = TRUE` to remove extra whitespace.

One issue with `MealPlan` is that there are a few with class `.noprice`. Oneo way to exclude them is to use `xpath` in `html_nodes` instead of CSS selectors. I don't know if there is a way to do it with CSS selectors. What I did below was extract both then take a set difference of them.

For the price I've used regular expression to get rid of the extra space in the price.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

url <- "https://www.hotelissima.fr/s/h/ile-maurice/mahebourg/astroea-beach.html?searchType=accomodation&searchId=4&guideId=&filters=&withFlights=false&airportCode=PAR&airport=Paris&search=astroea+beach&startdate=08%2F11%2F2021&stopdate=15%2F11%2F2021&duration=7&travelers=En+couple&travelType=&rooms%5B0%5D.nbAdults=2&rooms%5B0%5D.nbChilds=0&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B0%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B1%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B2%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B3%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B4%5D="

Price <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(".price") %>%
  html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% 
  str_replace("(\\d)\\s(\\d)", "\\1\\2")

RoomType <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(".room h3") %>%
  html_text(trim = TRUE)

AllMealPlans <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(".meal-plan-text") %>%
  html_text(trim = TRUE)

MealPlansNoPrice <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(".noprice .meal-plan-text") %>%
  html_text(trim = TRUE)

MealPlan <- setdiff(AllMealPlans, MealPlansNoPrice) 

NumberMealPlans <- length(MealPlan)
NumberRoomTypes <- length(RoomType)

MealPlanColumn <- MealPlan %>% rep(times=NumberRoomTypes)

RoomTypeColumn <- RoomType %>% 
  rep(each = NumberMealPlans)
  
bind_cols(RoomType = RoomTypeColumn, MealPlan = MealPlanColumn, Price = Price)
```

Comment: Thanks. However when I run the codes on another URL, I get an error message with the "setdiff" part: Error: Can't recycle `RoomType` (size 14) to match `MealPlan` (size 21).

Comment: url<- "https://www.hotelissima.fr/s/h/ile-maurice/bel-ombre/hotel-outrigger-mauritius.html?searchType=accomodation&searchId=4&guideId=&filters=&withFlights=false&airportCode=PAR&airport=Paris&search=hotel+outrigger+mauritius&startdate=08%2F11%2F2021&stopdate=15%2F11%2F2021&duration=7&travelers=En+couple&travelType=&rooms%5B0%5D.nbAdults=2&rooms%5B0%5D.nbChilds=0&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B0%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B1%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B2%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B3%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B4%5D="

Comment: @user3115933 I've updated the answer to take into account that the number of meal plans changes.

Comment: Good catch with trim = True

Comment: @student Thanks a lot. Is it possible to automatically remove a RoomType from the list in case no prices are displayed on the webpage for that specific RoomType?

Comment: @user3115933 I think it'll depend on how the page is setup.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map_dfr` from `purrr` to generate a wide DataFrame with separate columns for mealplans, then `pivot_longer` to get them into one column with the price info for the values. The initial list you pass into `map_dfr` would be the parent elements representing each room listing, gathered with css selector `.room`.

All the rooms at the provided url have the same combinations of price entries i.e. `Petit déj. + diner` and `All inclusive`. To cater for anything on other pages, you would either need to ascertain all cases, or, gather first all the `.room`, across all pages, into a single list, then use a method like [read.dcf](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dcf.html), to map out all possible cases and enter N/A where missing for a given listing. You would need to ensure to insert ":" for the key:value pairing for debian control format.

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

page <- read_html("https://www.hotelissima.fr/s/h/ile-maurice/mahebourg/astroea-beach.html?searchType=accomodation&searchId=4&guideId=&filters=&withFlights=false&airportCode=PAR&airport=Paris&search=astroea%20beach&startdate=08%2F11%2F2021&stopdate=15%2F11%2F2021&duration=7&travelers=En%20couple&travelType=&rooms%5B0%5D.nbAdults=2&rooms%5B0%5D.nbChilds=0&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B0%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B1%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B2%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B3%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B4%5D=")

df <- map_dfr(page |> html_elements(".room"), ~
data.frame(
  RoomType = .x |> html_element("h3") |> html_text(),
  `Petit Dej.+Diner` = .x |> html_element(".price") |> html_text() |> trimws(),
  `All inclusive` = .x |> html_element("div:nth-child(5) .price") |> html_text() |> trimws()
)) |>
  pivot_longer(!RoomType, names_to = "MealPlan", values_to = "Price")
```

---

Older R versions:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

page <- read_html("https://www.hotelissima.fr/s/h/ile-maurice/mahebourg/astroea-beach.html?searchType=accomodation&searchId=4&guideId=&filters=&withFlights=false&airportCode=PAR&airport=Paris&search=astroea%20beach&startdate=08%2F11%2F2021&stopdate=15%2F11%2F2021&duration=7&travelers=En%20couple&travelType=&rooms%5B0%5D.nbAdults=2&rooms%5B0%5D.nbChilds=0&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B0%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B1%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B2%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B3%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B4%5D=")

df <- map_dfr(page %>% html_elements(".room"), ~
data.frame(
  RoomType = .x %>% html_element("h3") %>% html_text(),
  `Petit Dej.+Diner` = .x %>% html_element(".price") %>% html_text() %>% trimws(),
  `All inclusive` = .x %>% html_element("div:nth-child(5) .price") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
)) %>%
  pivot_longer(!RoomType, names_to = "MealPlan", values_to = "Price")
```

---

`read.dcf` example to handle different price listings.

For read.dcf, I took the approach used by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) in their answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69278648), whereby `read.dcf` is used to map out all the meal plans, with a price, present, and put NA where a meal plan is not present for a given entry. For the xpath, I used an example given by [@tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) in their answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10076699)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

urls <- c(
  "https://www.hotelissima.fr/s/h/ile-maurice/mahebourg/astroea-beach.html?searchType=accomodation&searchId=4&guideId=&filters=&withFlights=false&airportCode=PAR&airport=Paris&search=astroea%20beach&startdate=08%2F11%2F2021&stopdate=15%2F11%2F2021&duration=7&travelers=En%20couple&travelType=&rooms%5B0%5D.nbAdults=2&rooms%5B0%5D.nbChilds=0&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B0%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B1%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B2%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B3%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B4%5D=",
  "https://www.hotelissima.fr/s/h/ile-maurice/bel-ombre/hotel-outrigger-mauritius.html?searchType=accomodation&searchId=4&guideId=&filters=&withFlights=false&airportCode=PAR&airport=Paris&search=hotel+outrigger+mauritius&startdate=08%2F11%2F2021&stopdate=15%2F11%2F2021&duration=7&travelers=En+couple&travelType=&rooms%5B0%5D.nbAdults=2&rooms%5B0%5D.nbChilds=0&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B0%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B1%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B2%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B3%5D=&rooms%5B0%5D.birthdates%5B4%5D="
)

entries <- purrr::map(urls, ~ read_html(.x) |> html_elements(".room")) |> unlist(recursive = F)

meal_df <- map_dfr(entries, ~ {
  prices <- .x %>%
    html_elements(".price") %>%
    html_text(trim = T)
  meal_text <- .x %>%
    html_elements(".price") |>
    html_elements(xpath = "./ancestor::div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'row')][1]//h4[@class='meal-plan-text']") |>
    html_text(trim = T)
  new <- paste(meal_text, prices, sep = ":")
  if (length(new) > 0) {
    as.data.frame(read.dcf(textConnection(new)))
  } else {
    NULL
  }
})

df <- map_df(entries, ~
data.frame(
  RoomType = .x |> html_element("h3") |> html_text()
))

listings <- cbind(df, meal_df)
```

Comment: You need `library(tidyr)` for `pivot_longer`. I think you meant to use `%>%` instead of `|>`.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for providing an answer. When I paste your set codes into RStudio, it flags a couple of lines with the following error message: Unexpected token '>'

Comment: For older R versions replace |> with %>%

Comment: @QHarr I am now getting this error message when running the codes: 
Error in html_elements(., ".room") : 
  could not find function "html_elements"

Comment: how old is your rvest version? You can replace `html_elements` with `html_nodes`

Comment: For new pipe operator in R you can check https://www.infoworld.com/article/3621369/use-the-new-r-pipe-built-into-r-41.html